# Event reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder how do I change the order of events.
Because I have to check when I took a focusOut with a click, if the click was inside the parent div, I can not let it happen the focusOut.

The problem, which is called first event focusOut the click event.

Is it possible to reverse the order of events? (Click - focusOut)?

http://jsfiddle.net/eL19p27L/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clean").click(function(){
        $(".alert").html("");
    });



    $(document).on({
        click: function(e){
            $(".alert").append("<p>click</p>");
        },
        focusin: function(e){
             $(".alert").append("<p>focusin</p>");
        },
        focusout: function(e){
            $(".alert").append("<p>focusout</p>");
        }

    })
});
```

It would be even better. If I could detect what the event might turn out to generate the fucusout. Hence check if it happened within the parent div, if not a focusIn, it leaves not give a focusOut.

ATT

Comment: You have to provide relevant code in question itself...

Comment: Is using `mousedown` an option for you? If not, you could just delayed the `focusout` handler

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do. Not in terms of events but in terms of behavior

Comment: @A. Wolff - I can delay using: setTimeout. How long should I put? ATT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the way you have your event handler set up on a common parent, you can't change the order of the events.

But, you can attach your event handlers to the specific objects you want to watch and then you can see events for that object only.

Or, you can look at the target of the event and see which object is which and you will see that the focusOut event is on a different object than the click event.

You can see the source of the event with `e.target`.

Example of looking at the object that is the source of the event: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/u5tLhes7/